# Tweepy Cursor Search - User input and Mention

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to have a user input search and a set search parameter in the api.search function of tweepy.

Essentially I want it like this:

```
print("input search term to search within Tesla tweets")
keyword = input()
print("Thanks!")
print("Tweets are cooking in the background now...")


# create list to append tweets to
tweets = []

# append all tweet data to list
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="@tesla" + keyword, tweet_mode="extended", count=10000, 
                       since="2018-08-01").items():
    tweets.append(tweet)
    word_string = repr(tweet)
```

But that won't work it just doesn't return any tweets

So I've tried it like this, which works, but it returns anything with @tesla in the tweet, not tweets mentioning tesla, so it's not ideal-

```
print("input search term to search within Tesla tweets")
keyword = input() + "@Tesla"
print("Thanks!")
print("Tweets are cooking in the background now...")

tweets = []

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, keyword, tweet_mode="extended", count=10000, 
                       since="2018-08-01").items():
    tweets.append(tweet)
    word_string = repr(tweet)
```

Is there any way I can do the first option or will I just have to live with it, it's not major, so it's not a big deal if so?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello - I am slightly confused. You say "it returns anything with @tesla in the tweet, not tweets mentioning tesla" - what is the difference?

Comment: It's really minor but makes the difference - so it should return tweets from all users tweeting at Tesla but most importantly excludes @Tesla replies and tweets - but the way I have currently includes the replies from Tesla as well as users tweeting at Tesla.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution to this problem, not sure how to close the question, but thought I'd put an answer for reference in case someone is having the same problem :)

Turns out you can't use boolean operators unless you have a premium twitter dev account.

So instead I just did the @tesla search, put it into the pandas dataframe, and then I filtered the pandas dataframe for the user input search term. Much easier to do, but limits my search terms is the only caveat.